# How can I add a link as a parameter inside a link so I can start from terminal

Tags: parsing, url, terminal, html-escape-characters, uri-scheme

I need to start the following link from the terminal

```
vidyo://login/?username=x&password=y&portal=https://nexi.alpha.vidyo.com&minimize=true
```

I get this error:

```
zsh: parse error near `&'
```

Now I'm a android programmer, so I did in a android app a console log on Uri.parse(link), but I get the same link, as "parsed"
But that doesn't feel right.
What do I need to do to my portal in order for the link to be parsed correctly

PS: I also tried this:

```
vidyo://login/?username=x&password=y&portal=https%3A%2F%2Fnexi.alpha.vidyo.com&minimize=true
```

But no luck
PS: I figured out that if I try

```
vidyo://login/?portal=https%3A%2F%2Fnexi.alpha.vidyo.com&minimize=true
```

It works, and the same for

```
vidyo://login/?username=x&password=y
```

Apparently adding the 3rd parameter gives me an parse error in terminal, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open "vidyo://login/?username=test2&password=test2&6portal=https://nexi.alpha.vidyo.com&minimize=false"` works, or `open vidyo://login/?username=test2%26password=test2%26portal=https://nexi.alpha.vidyo.com%26minimize=false` also works. The issue was the second "&"